# NSButtonCell when clicked disable other tablecolumn NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsbuttoncell

I have a NSTableView with two columns; A and B.

In column A and B there is a NSButtonCell (checkbox).

When I check the NSButtonCell checkbox in column A (value = 1) the NSButtonCell checkbox in column B should be disabled. When I uncheck the NSButtonCell checkbox in column A the NSButtonCell checkbox in column B should be enabled.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you want to disable button for each row?